# mysql multiple joins vs multiple queries

Tags: mysql, join

I was wondering about the merits of performing a multiple inner join VS multiple simple queries (to the localhost, so bandwidth & packet delay are not an issue).

The question has been asked before but most people advise that it depends on the particular query so here are my details:

I have around 20 simple tables (most of them are 3-5 columns) that all have a common column and i can join them with something like:

```
    SELECT a.id,a.a,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct b.b),GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.c).....
    FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id JOIN c ON b.id=c.id.......
    WHERE a.id='foo';
```

Since I use GROUP_CONCAT when I might get more than one values, I get just one row.

Alternatively I can do 20 simple select queries.

Which method do you think would be more preferable time-wise and cpu-wise?

Comment: Its dependent on data, Try it both ways and see what works best in YOUR case

Comment: `WHERE a.id='foo';` since you are joining around 1 row it should be fine with one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule you will do better with fewest queries.  The database has to do less work (19 fewer parses) the cache will probably be primed and the plan will be optimised for the problem at hand, not 5% of the problem.  Add in network latency for the round trips and it's getting quite concincing.  If, on the other hand, you find 20 separate queries cheaper then you may find the database is struggling with out of date stats or something and needs a bit of a tune up.